# Why java.lang.Runtime is made singleton ? singleton requirement?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I am just trying to come up the use cases where developer may need to use Singleton class . Here they are:-

1. When we need to maintain the synchronization among resources. For
   example in case of logging, multiple threads need to write to single
   log file in sequence. Here singleton helps as synchronization is
   required among different threads so that they write in single file
   in sequence.
2. When object creation itself is costly which means it time
   consuming operation . For example :- hibernate factory creation at
   start up. I am not saying this is the case in every situation but
   yes in some cases singleton helps here when same state needs to be
   shared across application and object creation is costly.
3. In case of business service objects , singleton helps as it
   forces us not to maintain the state of object which in turn makes
   code better unit testable.

Is my understanding on the right track?

I was looking for example of singleton in jdk and came across Runtime class  and thought why this singleton? As per my understanding reason should be the first one. For example we need synchronization so that two threads doesn't run GC at same instant. Is my logic correct?

Comment: What would it mean to instantiate a new `Runtime` in the same Java process?

Comment: Singleton kind of makes a class that would generally have everything static, and turns it into an object. The advantage is that it can now be passed into things.

Comment: @JoshLee Have a look at my answer. Isn't that what you imply by your question ? =)

Comment: @LittleChild Yes, my question was rhetorical.

Comment: It's not static. It still an call on an instance but only on one instance. The still are instance calls not static calls on a Class.

Answer (score 5):

> Every Java application has a single instance of class Runtime that
>   allows the application to interface with the environment in which the
>   application is running.

It feels intuitive that since the environment in which the Java program is executing is one, static thing which is not going to change, `Runtime` is made singleton.

The number of processors, the total RAM, etc are not going to change even if you spawn more and more threads. Thus, making `Runtime` a singleton instance optimizes the execution of the program by avoiding having to create an object  that contains the same information as 1000 other threads.

This is my understanding of it.

Comment: In that case Runtome could have all methods as static instead of singleton. Is n't it?

Answer (score -2):

Singletons are evil. They're really global variables in disguise. They're particularly bad for unit tests as once the singleton is loaded by a classloader, it's behaviour is fixed so you can't mock it. Your code will be fixed to call that dependency forever.

A better approach would be to use dependency injection to inject that dependency exactly to where it's needed, or to pass down the dependency through your code to where it's needed.

Have a read of: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil

Also you ask yourself why you would want to use a singleton. A singleton means one instance but it really means one instance per classloader. This may or may not be what you really desire for your solution.

Comment: +1 but as with every rule there are exceptions.  A singleton is appropriate for `Runtime` since there can only be one for the entire JVM.

Comment: That does not answer this question. It seems like copy-paste.

Comment: It's not a copy and paste. I was querying the rationale for using a singleton in the first place. Most of the time you don't need a singleton and it causes more problems than it solves.

Another point made was that a singleton could be used as some form of optimisation to prevent repeated creation of expensive objects. Again this a non-issue if dependency injection is adopted.

Comment: Dependency Injection is not always only solution to all problems in the world. If Runtime isn't singleton and someone could inject something else in its place, it will not give correct result. Dependency Injection is suitable for your app for test-ability, not for entire platform. If you want a virtual solution around it, you can build your own IRuntime and use it in your app.

Comment: Think you're missing the general point. Singletons how they generally used without DI are global variables as they can only be accessed via a global scope. I didn't say DI was a silver bullet solution.  DI is a better solution though because it externalises that dependency. Otherwise you have an implicit internal dependency which can never change.  Of course Sun's API was devised before DI really took off so maybe it was deemed a good idea then. It certainly not current good practice. I'm a practitioner of GOOS so externalizing all collaborators is a better design IMHO.

Comment: Furthermore any good DI framework will allow you to inject the same external collaborator into the places where it's needed with a particular scope i.e. (singleton rather than prototype) so ostensibly it's acting as a singleton without being an unknown internal dependency. An object should ideally only communicate with external known peers not internal ones. As Akash says, maybe a wrapper interface around Runtime.getRuntime() which is then injected is better design rather than using Runtime,getRuntime directly.